# Handling UI Event using Apollo Stack SSR

Tags: user-interface, reactjs, apollo

I'm currently migrating some React Client Side Rendering to Server Side Rendering but I can't figure out how to call a function, nothing happens once an element is triggered in the view.

I defined some functions in my component but once I click on the trigger, it's like the click has been removed once rendered.

```
match({ history, routes, location: req.url }, (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(500).send(err.message);
  }

  if (redirectLocation) {
    return res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
  }

  if (!renderProps) {
    return res.status(404).send('Not found');
  }

  const app = (
      <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient} >
        <RouterContext {...renderProps}/>
      </ApolloProvider>
  );

  renderToStringWithData(app).then((content) => {
    const initialState = {[apolloClient.reduxRootKey]: apolloClient.getInitialState() };
    const html = <Html content={content} state={initialState} />;

    res.status(200);
    res.send(`<!doctype html>\n${ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(html)}`);
    res.end();
});
```

Comment: Can you please share your code how you render the app in the server side?

Comment: I updated my question with more code

Comment: What do you mean by "it's like the click has been removed once rendered."?

Comment: As this is rendered on server, I don't have onclick prop once rendered

Comment: Have you done server-side rendering before with React without Apollo? There are some specifics about having to render on the client again, I don't think this issue is related to Apollo, but might just be a React thing.

Comment: Nope, that was the issue, and yes it needs to be rendered twice